# How to read multichannels ADC Value?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, adc, hal

I can read ADC value from ADC1_IN1 channel with this code `ADCValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);`  but ADC1 port (you can see on picture) has many channels. How can I read values from ADC1_IN2 ? How can I describe channel 2 in code ?

[image: ADC1 port]

Comment: what did ST say when you asked them?

Comment: I am not a friend of ST,so I didn't ask them.

Comment: http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/adc/ good tutorial

Comment: Thanks @BenceKaulics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set ADC Channel by `HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel` function :

```
ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;
sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2; // ADC Channel
sConfig.Rank = 1; //Rank (1-16) Rank: The rank in the regular group sequencer.
sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES; //ADC Sampling Times
sConfig.Offset = 0; // Reserved

if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK) {
    //Error
}
```

[Description of STM32F4xx HAL drivers](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/2f/71/ba/b8/75/54/47/cf/DM00105879.pdf/files/DM00105879.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105879.pdf)

Comment: How will be usage of GetValue() Function ?                                                            `HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);`